# Tail Bounds of Spectral Norm of unbounded Chi-Squared Vector

Tags: probability-theory, convex-optimization, probability-limit-theorems, upper-lower-bounds, distribution-tails

Let $Z=(z_0,z_2,...,z_{N-1})$  be a vector with Chi-square distributed random variables ($zi=a_ia_i^*, a_i:CN(0,1)$ :Complex scalar gaussian), and consider  $f:R^N->R, (f(Z)=||Z||_2$) as function unbounded with respect to **Z**. Is it possible to calculate its tail bound with the Martingale difference sequence (**MDS**), from Azuma-Hoeffding? And if yes, How I should calculate  MDS bounds ($b_i$) in which $|D_i|<=b_i$ might be bounded, where Di are defined as

$$
D_i=E[||Z||_2|z_0,z_1,...,z_i]-E[||Z||_2|z_0,z_1,...,z_{i-1}]****
$$
**How it is possible to calculate these Conditional Expecation?**